# How can I deploy a Stream Analytics job through VSTS?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have looked far and wide but can’t find any tutorials on how to deploy a stream analytics job from VSTS using continuous integration and deployment!

Has anybody out there done this before? If so I’d appreciate a push in the right direction!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the doc you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-tools-for-visual-studio-cicd

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-tools-visual-studio-cicd-vsts

You will also need ARM template and this link can be useful for you:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david/2017/07/20/building-azure-stream-analytics-resources-via-arm-templates-part-2-the-template/

Comment: Not what OP is asking for. ARM templates are different to CDCI with VSTS.

Comment: To generate CICD with StreamAnalytics Job you need to use ARM template. 
So probably this is partially answer for the question.

Comment: I've added link to general documentation.